# grep phone numbers from html files

Tags: grep, find, xargs

I have backup my forum (vBulletin) as .html files and it's contains phone numbers 
I'm try to grep those phone numbers using xargs and egrep .. like:

```
   find -iname \*showthread.php\* | xargs egrep "[[:digit:]]{7}"
```

i know my command it's missing and it's print all contains files

my request it's to print the phone numbers only
the phone numbers is (7 digits) and should be start with either 
9xxxxxx or 6xxxxxx or 5xxxxxx

please help 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find -iname \*showthread.php\* | xargs grep -hEo '\<[569][[:digit:]]{6}\>'
```

The `-h` options suppresses the filename, so your output should only be 7-digit numbers.

Comment: I guess they select 7 digit from any numbers mentions in *.html files for example 43347563486852346654325.gif (6654325)  2334677498347543.gif  (98347543) .. due i have replace the 569 with any other numbers , i also got result which is impossible!!  due phone numbers in my html files it should be start with 5 or 6 or 9  with length 7 digits only no other numbers are their.  may i need to but space before and after?

Comment: ok it's work now after i add one space ' \<[569... then i got only the phone numbers ,,thanks :)